# How to use a loop function to create a new variable for each item in the dataset

Tags: r, loops

My current dataset has 50 test items, and each item occupies 4 rows.  They're broken down by assessment period (pre and post) and by group (0 vs. 1).  To demonstrate, here's my sample dataset with just two items.

```
df <- data.frame(group_membership=c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1" ),
             item=c("bk_item_1_key", "bk_item_1_key", "bk_item_1_key", "bk_item_1_key", "bk_item_2_key", "bk_item_2_key", "bk_item_2_key", "bk_item_2_key" ),
             assessment_period=c("pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre", "post"),
             proportion_correct=c(0.5949,0.7468,0.6588,0.8235,
                                  0.8734,0.9114,0.8353,0.8235))
```

I would like to extract each item from the original dataset and compute a new variable called "total_student_correct". I have been successful using the following code.

```
df.item1.long <- df%>% filter(item=="bk_item_1_key") %>%
group_by(group_membership, assessment_period) %>%
mutate(total_student_correct=case_when(
group_membership=="0" ~ proportion_correct*79,
group_membership=="1" ~ proportion_correct * 85)) %>%
arrange(group_membership, desc(assessment_period))

df.item2.long <- df%>%
filter(item=="bk_item_2_key") %>%
group_by(group_membership, assessment_period) %>%
mutate(total_student_correct=case_when(
group_membership=="0" ~ proportion_correct*79,
group_membership=="1" ~ proportion_correct * 85)) %>%
arrange(group_membership, desc(assessment_period))
```

However, since I have to extract each item for a total of 50 items, this process is very tedious and error prone.  Is there a more efficient way to do some kind of a loop so that I can end up with 50 objects (df.item1.long,df.item2.long, etc) with much less syntax?  I'm a beginner in R and I would greatly appreciate any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would push back against the impulse to make 50 objects. That approach is indeed error-prone and creates a whole new challenge for yourself to manage and track those objects and make sure they holistically change or don't change the way you intend.

A more powerful approach would be to make a list, where all 50 objects are packaged together inside one object. That makes it much easier to track and make sure you are acting on all the components or none. `base::split()` will do this for you.

I'd also suggest you do your calculations in one go, rather than item by item. Rather than hard-coding the question numbers, you can join to a table where you keep those.

```
question_n <- data.frame(group_membership = c("0", "1"),
                         questions = c(79, 85))
df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(question_n) %>%
  mutate(total_student_correct = proportion_correct * questions)
df_list <- split(df2, df2$item)
df_list
```

Result will be a list. You can access each piece with, for instance, `df_list$bk_item_1_key`.

```
$bk_item_1_key
  group_membership          item assessment_period proportion_correct questions total_student_correct
1                0 bk_item_1_key               pre             0.5949        79               46.9971
2                0 bk_item_1_key              post             0.7468        79               58.9972
3                1 bk_item_1_key               pre             0.6588        85               55.9980
4                1 bk_item_1_key              post             0.8235        85               69.9975

$bk_item_2_key
  group_membership          item assessment_period proportion_correct questions total_student_correct
5                0 bk_item_2_key               pre             0.8734        79               68.9986
6                0 bk_item_2_key              post             0.9114        79               72.0006
7                1 bk_item_2_key               pre             0.8353        85               71.0005
8                1 bk_item_2_key              post             0.8235        85               69.9975
```

Comment: Almost a dead heat! ;=)  I fully support your pushback against creating fifty-odd objects.

Comment: Wow... another great and clever solution that will streamline my work flow... literally saved me pages and pages of script by doing all of my calcuations in one go.  And yes, thanks for your advice against creating 50 objects and for showing me how to store all objects in one list!!

Comment: Any chance someone could help me subtract total_student_correct at pre assessment from total_student_correct at post from the same output above?  So for example, for the first two rows of bk_item_1 (group_membership=0), there will be a new column called "difference" where the two rows would include value of 12 (59-47) and the last two rows of bk_item_1(group_membership=1) would include the value of 14 (70-56). Thank you for any input you can provide.

Comment: might be easiest to use `%>% pivot_wider(names_from = assessment_period, values_from = proportion_correct)` after the mutate step above, then you can `%>% mutate(difference = post - pre)`

Comment: Thank you so much, Jon, for providing such a succinct solution to my problem.  I was able to take your suggestion and made it work for my own needs.  I'm grateful for your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

You don't state exactly what your expected output is, but I believe this will come close.  It's based on the tidyverse and, in particular, the `group_map()` function.  This takes a single argument, which is a function, and applies it to the current group of a grouped data frame.  The current group data is conventionally called `.x` and the columns that define the group are called `.y`.  `group_map() returns a list of tibbles, so` bind_rows` combines the list into one.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
       .x  %>%
        group_by(group_membership, assessment_period) %>%
        mutate(total_student_correct=case_when(
          group_membership=="0" ~ proportion_correct*79,
          group_membership=="1" ~ proportion_correct * 85)) %>%
        arrange(group_membership, desc(assessment_period))      
    }, 
    .keep = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   group_membership, assessment_period [4]
  group_membership item          assessment_period proportion_correct total_student_correct
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>                          <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 0                bk_item_1_key pre                            0.595                  47.0
2 0                bk_item_1_key post                           0.747                  59.0
3 1                bk_item_1_key pre                            0.659                  56.0
4 1                bk_item_1_key post                           0.824                  70.0
5 0                bk_item_2_key pre                            0.873                  69.0
6 0                bk_item_2_key post                           0.911                  72.0
7 1                bk_item_2_key pre                            0.835                  71.0
8 1                bk_item_2_key post                           0.824                  70.0
>
```

The body of the function provided to `group_map()` is essentially what you do for one group in your example, without the (now redundant) call to `filter()` at the start of the pipe.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Your solution is very clever and efficient!