# Period (`.`) in dplyr::summarise for referencing table within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following table:

```
# Inputs
require(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(g = rep(x = c("A", "B", "C"), times = c(3, 5, 7)),
             a = sample(x = 1:100, size = 15), 
             b = sample(x = 1:100, size = 15))

df

# A tibble: 15 × 3
   g         a     b
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 A        87     8
 2 A        35    51
 3 A        40    74
 4 B        30    50
 5 B        12    98
 6 B        31    86
 7 B        97    76
 8 B        64    84
 9 C        14    46
10 C        71    17
11 C        67    62
12 C        23    92
13 C        79    54
14 C        85    35
15 C        37    79
```

I also define a function (for this example, very simple) that takes a whole data frame and returns a single numeric value:

```
# Function
myFUN <- function(x){
  mean(x$a + x$b)
}
```

What I am looking for is to apply the `group_by` and `summarise` functions to get a table with the results for each group.

I thought it could be as simple as doing the following:

```
# What I got (incorrect results)
df %>%  
  
  group_by(g) %>% 
  
  summarise(res = myFUN(.))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  g       res
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      112.
2 B      112.
3 C      112.
```

But as you can see, all the result (`res`) values are the same, because `.` refers to the whole initial table and not to the subset tables withing each group.

I leave an example of the expected result using a loop:

```
# Expected
out <- list()
for(i in unique(df$g)){
  out[[length(out) + 1]] <- tibble(g = i,
                                   res = df %>% filter(g == i) %>% myFUN)
}

out |> bind_rows()

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  g       res
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      98.3
2 B     126. 
3 C     109.
```

**Solution** (taken from the answer of @Limey)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  
  group_map(.f = function(.x, .y){
    .x %>% 
      
      summarise(res = myFUN(.)) %>% 
      
      mutate(g = .y$g, .before = 1)
  }) %>% 
  
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: To do what you want to do (though there are, I think, easier ways), you need `dplyr::group_map` or one of its siblings.  See, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76542201/how-to-use-a-loop-function-to-create-a-new-variable-for-each-item-in-the-dataset).

Comment: @Limey Thank you. I have been trying with `group_map` and `group_modify`, but they are not exactly what I am looking for. The closest is `group_map`, but it only returns a list with the values of the function you give it, so it doesn't allow to be used inside a `summarise`. My reproducible example is very simplified, but in the real world I have is a lot of `myFUN`s that take complete tables and return unique values (spatial metrics, to be exact). So I am thinking that the solution could be used within a `summarise` call.

Comment: No.  You misunderstand.  You use `summarise` inside `group_map`, not the other way round.

Comment: @Limey You're right, I don't get it. I'm not clear where I would have to place the `summarise` (around `myFUN`? inside `myFUN`?) to achieve the output table shown in my reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your expected results, but I think this gives you what you want.  `.x` takes the place of your `.` because `group_map` expects a function with two arguments.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      .x %>% 
        summarise(res = mean(a + b)) %>% 
        add_column(g = .y$g, .before = 1)
    }
  ) %>% bind_rows()
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  g       res
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      78.7
2 B     101. 
3 C     117.
```

And, of course, this can be reduced to

```
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  summarise(res = mean(a + b))
```

(with identical results) in this case, but I accept you have simplified your real use-case to produce your MWE.